# Can't get multiline textbox with windows forms

Tags: windows, powershell, winforms

So I'm trying to make a simple gui to display output in a textbox with windows forms. It seems straightforward enough. Everything is working so far, except that I cannot get the textbox to be more than one line. After some struggling, I discovered the .multiline property needs to be set to true. Awesome. I try that, and no luck. I am posting my code and a screenshot of what I get. Maybe someone can help explain.

FYI: I am on a system with powershell 5.1, so maybe that's the issue?

Code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$testText = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\test.txt

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Data Entry Form'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,500)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'Display the text'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,130)
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$textBox.Multiline = $true
$textBox.ReadOnly = $true
#$textBox.Text = $testText
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)

$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,50)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$okButton.Text = 'GO'
#$okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
#$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$okButton.Add_Click({
    $textBox.Text = $testText
})
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

$form.Topmost = $true

$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

EOF/////////
```

I tried setting multiline to true, and adjusting the size of the textbox. I created a multiline text file to get read in and displayed in the textbox. Since the textbox seems to be ignoring any sizing, it just displays part of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Size of the TextBox you're setting `(260,20)` defines a quite (random) low Height, you can probably see 1 line, maximum.
Since the TextBox's `ScrollBars` Property is omitted and it defaults to `[ScrollBars]::None`, you cannot scroll the TextBox.

`Get-Content [<file path>]` returns a collection of lines of text. Better specify the `-Raw` parameter, so you get the entire content, and you also preserve the original new line chars, if present. This is also much faster, because you're using the file's content to set the Text of a Control
If you don't get the result expected, try to specify a `-Delimiter`

A few suggestions:

- Specify the Font to use. The current default Font is `Segoe UI, 9pt`. Don't use `Microsoft Sans Serif` (the previous default Font)
- Set the Font to the parent Form. All child Controls inherit the Font from their Parent
- Instead of a TextBox, create a RichTextBox. This Control is multiline by default. It also can determine which ScrollBars to use, based on the Text content. A vertical ScrollBar appears automatically, in this case
- You can define how many lines a TextBox or RichTextBox shows, multiplying the `Font.Height` value (see the code). You can use the resulting value as the `Height` of the Control
- Instead of moving the Focus when the Form is shown (which *may* cause cascading effects, and trigger validation events), set the `TabIndex` of your Controls. The focusable Control with the lower `TabIndex` becomes the first `ActiveControl` when the Form is loaded).
  The `TabIndex` sequence also determines which Control becomes active next, when the `TAB` key is pressed. Some Controls cannot get Focus, as the Label (or the Form itself)

**Note:**
I assume you want to load the file's content when the Form is loaded, not when the `$okButton` Button is pressed, because that Button appears to be the `AcceptButton`: when it's interacted with, the Form closes and sets the Dialog result

To showcase the changes, I've also refactored the syntax used to declare the objects. That's just because I cannot stand the other one :) It's not a crucial aspect to the overall functionality here

---

```
using namespace System.Drawing
using namespace System.Windows.Forms

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
[Application]::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault($false)
Clear-Host

$testText = Get-Content -Raw $PSScriptRoot\test.txt

$form = [Form] @{
    AcceptButton = $okButton    
    ClientSize = [Size]::new(500,500)
    Font = [Font]::new("Segoe UI", 9.25)
    Location = [Point]::new(10,20)
    StartPosition = [FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen;
    Text = 'Data Entry Form'
}

$label = [Label] @{
    Location = [Point]::new(10,20)
    Size = [Size]::new(280,20)
    Text = 'Display the text'
}

$textBox = [RichTextBox] @{
    Location = [Point]::new(10,130)
    ReadOnly = $true
    Size = [Size]::new(260, $form.Font.Height * 9) # Set Height to show 9 lines of text
    TabIndex = 0  #Lowest TabIndex = first ActiveControl
    Text = $testText
}

$okButton = [Button] @{
    DialogResult = [DialogResult]::OK
    Location = [Point]::new(20,50)
    Name = 'OK'
    Size = [Size]::new(75,23)
    TabIndex = 1
    Text = 'GO'
}

#$okButton.Add_Click({$textBox.Text = $testText})

$form.Controls.Add($label)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

if ($form.ShowDialog() -eq [DialogResult]::OK){
    Write-Host $okButton.Name "Button Clicked"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped a lot. Had no idea about RichTextBox!